# Sql query for data stored as JSON

Tags: javascript, sql, json, sql-server

I have data stored in column as JSON, as shown below:

{"category":{"value":CAT, "demo":A.......

I want to query in SSMS and want an output like:

CAT

I tried "SELECT JSON_QUERY(TABLENAME,'$.CATEGORY') FROM TABLENAME" which gave result of the

{"value":CAT, "demo":A....... but I want only CAT. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON_VALUE to get specific values.

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(TABLENAME,'$.CATEGORY.VALUE') AS Value
```

JSON_QUERY is for JSON fragments.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2):

You should use JSON_VALUE.

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(ColumnName, '$.category.value') FROM TableName
```

Take note of the first parameter, it should be the column name, not the table name (as opposed to your example).

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid JSON string? I can see in your example category.value = CAT. That should be wrapped in double quotes "CAT".

Comment: My apologies, actual data has {"category":{"value":"CAT", "demo":"A".......